# Scala's implicit conversion isn't working on java.util.List

Tags: java, scala

I'm a scala newer, and i'm trying to use scala in my java project. I want to treat `java.util.List` like `Array` in scala code, and i know a little abount implicit conversion and think it may help me. But after  a implicit conversion converting `java.util.ArrayList[String]` to `Array[String]` defined. My code still doesn't work. Here is my code, can anyone give me some suggesions.

```
    implicit def collection2Arr(collection:java.util.ArrayList[String]) :Array[String] = {
            return collection.toArray(new Array[String](collection.size()))
    }

    val arrayList = new util.ArrayList[String]()
    arrayList.map(x=>x+"1")
```

Comment: Implicit conversion has made effect, `java.util.ArrayList[String]`  has converted to `Array[String]`,  but `map` is a method in trait `TraversableLike`. It seems  that the converted `Array[String]` can not be converted to `TraversableLike`,  what should I do if i want to use method in  `TraversableLike`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your example to work, Scala would have to chain 2 implicit conversions (one `j.u.ArrayList` to `scala.Array`, another from `scala.Array` to `ArrayOps`. In general, such technique would bring exponential number of possibilities to check (traverse over *all* possible chains of implicit conversions) and would make developers literally unable to tell which one worked. Thus, Scala checks only for 1 possible conversion, and, since there's no `map` neither in `ArrayList` nor in `Array`, fails.

Answering your questions, your should use `JavaConverters`:

```
scala> val l = new ArrayList[String]()
l: java.util.ArrayList[String] = []

scala> import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

scala> l.asScala
res0: scala.collection.mutable.Buffer[String] = Buffer()

scala> l.asScala.toArray
res1: Array[String] = Array()

scala> l.asScala.toArray.map(x => x + "1")
res2: Array[String] = Array()
```